# Create custom JSON from array of objects

Tags: javascript

Using angularjs here:

I have array of object as below. Below it just example showing 2 objects but it can me more than 2.

```
[
 {
  "name": "John",
  "control": "1",
  "available": "true",  
  "comment": "n1",
  "value": "v1"
 },
 {
  "name": "Peter",  
  "control": "2",
  "available": "true",  
  "type": "integer",
  "comment": "n2",
  "value": "v2",
   "userOptions": [
   {
    "text": "Utah",
    "value": "UT"    
   },
   {
    "text": "New York",
    "value": "NY"
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

I want to create a json as:

```
"data":
{
  "John": 
   {
     "control": "1",
     "features": {
          "available": true
      },
      "value": "v1",
      "comment": "c1"
   } ,
 "Peter": 
   {
     "control": "2",
     "features": {
          "available": true,
          "userOptions": {
              "Utah": "UT",
              "New York": "NY",
          }
      },
      "value": "v2",
      "comment": "c2"
   }
}
```

So if you see the json structure depends on control key because of which some extra param will be added.
While some of the keys like control,value, comment remains same.

Could anyone share how can I create the above json. I want to create above in my button event.

```
$scope.submit = function (isValid) {

if(isValid)
{
   $scope.data.filter(function (item, index) {

      for (var key in item) {

        }                   
   });
}
```

Comment: You should note that the first structure supports multiple users with the same name, while the second (wanted one) don't. Anyway, [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) could be an option for you if you can be sure that names are unique.

Comment: as @Shidersz says. `Array.reduce()` is typically used here. Also as you are moving to `unique names` you might want to start with `Set()` first to get all unique names, that would make things a little easier.

Comment: Agreed regarding `Array.reduce`. Lodash has a method for this called groupBy `_.groupBy(peopleArray, "name")`. You could also refer to their implementation. https://lodash.com/docs/#groupBy

Comment: @AlexMA: `groupBy` will create arrays of elements grouped under each key.  `reduce` is easy enough here.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Oops, you are correct. I haven't used lodash in a while. Anyway, a library isn't necessary for anything this simple. Please disregard my previous comment.

Comment: @AlexMA: As a library author myself (https://ramdajs.com) I find the use of libraries very helpful.  But we need to know when they are appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should note that the first structure supports multiple users with the same name, while the second (wanted one) don't. Anyway, [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) could be an option for you if you can be sure that names are unique.

## Example:

```js
const input = [{"name":"John","control":"1","available":"true","comment":"n1","value":"v1"},{"name":"Peter","control":"2","available":"true","type":"integer","comment":"n2","value":"v2","userOptions":[{"text":"Utah","value":"UT"},{"text":"New York","value":"NY"}]}];

let res = input.reduce((acc, user) =>
{
    let {name, available, userOptions, ...others} = user;
    acc[name] = {...others, features: {available: JSON.parse(available)}};

    if (userOptions !== undefined)
    {
        acc[name].features.userOptions = {};

        userOptions.forEach(({text, value}) =>
        {
            acc[name].features.userOptions[text] = value;
        });
    }

    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: This is missing a level.  `features.Utah` should be `features.userOptions.Utah`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks for your feedback, I missed that!

Comment: Looks like the OP used your answer and wrote a new question. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875141/create-custom-json

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = [
     {
      "name": "John",
      "control": "1",
      "available": "true",  
      "comment": "n1",
      "value": "v1"
     },
     {
      "name": "Peter",  
      "control": "2",
      "available": "true",  
      "type": "integer",
      "comment": "n2",
      "value": "v2",
       "userOptions": [
       {
        "text": "Utah",
        "value": "UT"    
       },
       {
        "text": "New York",
        "value": "NY"
       }
      ]
     }
    ];

    const convert = items =>
      items.reduce((result, { name, control, value, comment, available, userOptions }) => ({
        ...result,
        [name]: {
          control,
          value,
          comment,
          features: {
            available: available === 'true',
            ...(Array.isArray(userOptions) && {
              userOptions: userOptions.reduce((options, { text, value }) => ({
                ...options,
                [text]: value
              }), {})
            })
          }
        }
      }), {});

    console.log(convert(data));
```

Comment: This is nice, but it does one thing that might be considered a bug: it adds a `userOptions` object to "John", even though John didn't have that node to begin with.

Comment: An interesting difference between your solution and mine is that I assume that there might be other fields that simply need to be copied.  I don't know if that's the case, but it felt more flexible.  The one from Shidersz is similar to mine in this.  Of course if additional fields need to be moved into `features`, all bets are off.

Comment: Just modified the code to remove `userOptions` if not present in the source object, thank you.
Yeah, not sure if the additional fields need to be put into the `features` or in the root...

Answer (score 1):

I would start by breaking this down into smaller functions.  I might end up with a solution like this

```js
const makeObject = kvs => 
  kvs .reduce ( (a, {text, value} ) => ( {...a, [text]: value} ), {})

const makeFeatures = ( {available, userOptions: uo, ...rest} ) =>
   ( {...rest, features: {
     ...( available ? {available} : {}),
     ...( uo ? {userOptions: makeObject (uo) } : {} )
   } } )

const transform = (people) => 
  people.reduce( (a, {name, ...rest} ) => ( {...a, [name]: makeFeatures ({...rest}) }), {})

const people = [{"available": "true", "comment": "n1", "control": "1", "name": "John", "value": "v1"}, {"available": "true", "comment": "n2", "control": "2", "name": "Peter", "type": "integer", "userOptions": [{"text": "Utah", "value": "UT"}, {"text": "New York", "value": "NY"}], "value": "v2"}]

console .log (
  transform (people)
)
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

### Thought Process

I would start this process from the outside in, first writing a version of `transform` like this:

```js
const transform = (people) => 
  people.reduce( (a, {name, ...rest} ) => ( {...a, [name]: {...rest} }), {})
```

which simply converts `people` to

```
{
  John: {...}
  Peter: {...}
}
```

and those internal object have all the original fields except for `name`.

Then I would write a version of `makeFeatures` that looks something like:

```js
const makeFeatures = ( {available, ...rest} ) =>
   ( {...rest, features: {available} } )
```

so that `makeFeatures(people[1])` would result in something like

```
{
  comment: "n1",
  control: "1",
  features: {
    available: "true"
  },
  value: "v1"
}
```

and for `people[2]` it would also include `userOptions` and `type`.

Then I can adjust `transform` like this:

```js
const transform = (people) => 
  people.reduce( (a, {name, ...rest} ) => ( {...a, [name]: makeFeatures({...rest}) }), {})
```

so that the main function will create our name-based object with `available` extracted into features for each person.

Now that `available` is there, we need to handle `userOptions` as well.  This one is slightly more complicated, as it may or may not be included.  So I change `makeFeatures` like this:

```js
const makeFeatures = ( {available, userOptions, ...rest} ) =>
   ( {...rest, features: {available, ...( userOptions ? {userOptions} : {} )} } )
```

This includes `userOptions inside`features`only if it's in the person object.  Seeing this makes me wonder if`available` might also only sometimes be included, and to be safe, I will rewrite like this:

```js
const makeFeatures = ( {available, userOptions, ...rest} ) =>
   ( {...rest, features: {
     ...( available ? {available} : {}),
     ...( userOptions ? {userOptions} : {} )
   } } )
```

So now the only thing left to do is convert the `userOptions` object from `[{text, value}, {text2, value2}, ...]` into `{text: value, text2: value2, ...}`.  We write a new function for that:

```js
const convertOptions = userOptions => 
  userOptions .reduce ( (a, {text, value} ) => ( {...a, [text]: value} ), {})
```

and we alter makeFeatures to use it:

```js
const makeFeatures = ( {available, userOptions, ...rest} ) =>
   ( {...rest, features: {
     ...( available ? {available} : {}),
    ...( userOptions ? {userOptions: convertOptions (userOptions) } : {} )
   } } )
```

We now have working code.  It meets the specs as we have them so far, and it's fairly easy to see how we could adjust to new requirements.

But there are two bits of cleanup I would still like to do.  First, all the uses of "userOptions" inside `makeFeatures` seems untidy.  I would add an abbreviation like this:

```
const makeFeatures = ( {available, userOptions: uo, ...rest} ) =>
   ( {...rest, features: {
     ...( available ? {available} : {}),
     ...( uo ? {userOptions: convertOptions  (uo) } : {} )
   } } )
```

This is a minor consideration, and some people would not approve, but I find it easier on the eyes.

Second, we can note that `convertOptions` has nothing to do with options.  It's a generic function that takes an array of `text`/`value` pairs and converts them into an object.  So I would rename that to `makeObject`, and possibly move it from this block to some utility code.

While this all sounds long and involved, all these steps together took under ten minutes.  I was running it in a REPL with instant feedback of my changes, and it really wasn't complicated.  Writing it up here took much more time.